# Spring Data JPA - repositories with IN, `=`, LIKE for List

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa

I have two entieties:

```java
@Entity
public class First {
    ...
    @OneToMany
    private Set<Second> secondSet;
    ...
}
```

```java
@Entity
public class Second {
    ...
    @ManyToOne
    private First first;
    ...
}
```

And repository:

```java
public interface FirstRepository extends JpaRepository<First, Long> {

    List<First> findAllBySecondSetIn(List<Second> secondSet);

    List<First> findAllBySecondSetEquals(List<Second> secondSet);

    List<First> findAllBySecndSetLike(List<Second> secondSet);
}
```

What is the difference between these methods? I know how it works for individual elements as an argument, but not for collections.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think they are standard JpaRepository[1](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/2.2.4.RELEASE/api/) interface but by the naming conventions followed,I think they can be translated into following:

1. Set IN : The result can have more elements than the parameter but all parameters are included in the result.
2. Set EQUALS: The results should be same as the parameters
3. Set LIKE: The results can have 0 or more items as in the parameters.